# How to prove that terms of a first-order language are well-founded?

Tags: coq

Currently, I've started working on proving theorems about first-order logic in Coq([VerifiedMathFoundations](https://github.com/georgydunaev/VerifiedMathFoundations)). I've proved deduction theorem, but then I got stuck with lemma 1 for theorem of correctness. So I've formulated one elegant piece of the lemma compactly and I invite the community to look at it. That is an incomplete the proof of well-foundness of the terms. How to get rid of the pair of "admit"s properly?

```
(* PUBLIC DOMAIN *)
Require Export Coq.Vectors.Vector.
Require Export Coq.Lists.List.
Require Import Bool.Bool.
Require Import Logic.FunctionalExtensionality.
Require Import Coq.Program.Wf.

Definition SetVars  := nat.
Definition FuncSymb := nat.
Definition PredSymb := nat.
Record FSV := {
 fs : FuncSymb;
 fsv : nat;
}.
Record PSV := MPSV{
 ps : PredSymb;
 psv : nat;
}.
Inductive Terms : Type :=
| FVC :> SetVars -> Terms
| FSC (f:FSV) : (Vector.t Terms (fsv f)) -> Terms.

Definition rela : forall (x y:Terms), Prop.
Proof.
fix rela 2.
intros x y.
destruct y as [s|f t].
+ exact False.
+ refine (or _ _).
  exact (Vector.In x t).
  simple refine (@Vector.fold_left Terms Prop _ False (fsv f) t).
  intros Q e.
  exact (or Q (rela x e)).
Defined.

Definition snglV {A} (a:A) := Vector.cons A a 0 (Vector.nil A).

Definition wfr : @well_founded Terms rela.
Proof.
clear.
unfold well_founded.
assert (H : forall (n:Terms) (a:Terms), (rela a n) -> Acc rela a).
{ fix iHn 1.
  destruct n.
  + simpl. intros a b; destruct b.
  + simpl. intros a Q. destruct Q as [L|R].
    * admit.  (* smth like apply Acc_intro. intros m Hm. apply (iHn a). exact Hm. *)
    * admit.  (* like in /Arith/Wf_nat.v *)
}
intros a.
simple refine (H _ _ _).
exact (FSC (Build_FSV 0 1) (snglV a)).
simpl.
apply or_introl.
constructor.
Defined.
```

It is also available here: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/UqpxM5Xb).

*Update*: At least transitivity is needed for well-foundness. I also started a proof, but didn't finished.

```
Fixpoint Tra (a b c:Terms) (Hc : rela c b) (Hb : rela b a) {struct a}: rela c a.
Proof.
destruct a.
+ simpl in * |- *.
  exact Hb.
+ simpl in * |- *.
  destruct Hb.
  - apply or_intror.
    revert f t H .
    fix RECU 1.
    intros f t H.
    (* ... *)
Admitted.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by defining a height function on `Terms`, and showing that decreasing `rela` implies decreasing heights:

```
Require Export Coq.Vectors.Vector.
Require Export Coq.Lists.List.
Require Import Bool.Bool.
Require Import Logic.FunctionalExtensionality.
Require Import Coq.Program.Wf.

Definition SetVars  := nat.
Definition FuncSymb := nat.
Definition PredSymb := nat.
Record FSV := {
 fs : FuncSymb;
 fsv : nat;
}.
Record PSV := MPSV{
 ps : PredSymb;
 psv : nat;
}.

Unset Elimination Schemes.
Inductive Terms : Type :=
| FVC :> SetVars -> Terms
| FSC (f:FSV) : (Vector.t Terms (fsv f)) -> Terms.
Set Elimination Schemes.

Definition Terms_rect (T : Terms -> Type)
                      (H_FVC : forall sv, T (FVC sv))
                      (H_FSC : forall f v, (forall n, T (Vector.nth v n)) -> T (FSC f v)) :=
  fix loopt (t : Terms) : T t :=
    match t with
    | FVC sv  => H_FVC sv
    | FSC f v =>
      let fix loopv s (v : Vector.t Terms s) : forall n, T (Vector.nth v n) :=
        match v with
        | @Vector.nil _ => Fin.case0 _
        | @Vector.cons _ t _ v => fun n => Fin.caseS' n (fun n => T (Vector.nth (Vector.cons _ t _ v) n))
                                                      (loopt t)
                                                      (loopv _ v)
        end in
      H_FSC f v (loopv _ v)
    end.

Definition Terms_ind := Terms_rect.

Fixpoint height (t : Terms) : nat :=
  match t with
  | FVC _ => 0
  | FSC f v => S (Vector.fold_right (fun t acc => Nat.max acc (height t)) v 0)
  end.

Definition rela : forall (x y:Terms), Prop.
Proof.
fix rela 2.
intros x y.
destruct y as [s|f t].
+ exact False.
+ refine (or _ _).
  exact (Vector.In x t).
  simple refine (@Vector.fold_left Terms Prop _ False (fsv f) t).
  intros Q e.
  exact (or Q (rela x e)).
Defined.

Require Import Lia.

Definition wfr : @well_founded Terms rela.
Proof.
apply (Wf_nat.well_founded_lt_compat _ height).
intros t1 t2. induction t2 as [sv2|f2 v2 IH]; simpl; try easy.
intros [t_v|t_sub]; apply Lt.le_lt_n_Sm.
{ clear IH. induction t_v; simpl; lia. }
revert v2 IH t_sub; generalize (fsv f2); clear f2.
intros k v2 IH t_sub.
enough (H : exists n, rela t1 (Vector.nth v2 n)).
{ destruct H as [n H]. apply IH in H. clear IH t_sub.
  transitivity (height (Vector.nth v2 n)); try lia; clear H.
  induction v2 as [|t2 m v2 IHv2].
  - inversion n.
  - apply (Fin.caseS' n); clear n; simpl; try lia.
    intros n. specialize (IHv2 n). lia. }
clear IH.
assert (H : Vector.fold_right (fun t Q => Q \/ rela t1 t) v2 False).
{ revert t_sub; generalize False.
  induction v2 as [|t2 n v2]; simpl in *; trivial.
  intros P H; specialize (IHv2 _ H); clear H.
  induction v2 as [|t2' n v2 IHv2']; simpl in *; tauto. }
clear t_sub.
induction v2 as [|t2 k v2 IH]; simpl in *; try easy.
destruct H as [H|H].
- apply IH in H.
  destruct H as [n Hn].
  now exists (Fin.FS n).
- now exists Fin.F1.
Qed.
```

(Note the use of the custom induction principle, which is needed because of the nested inductives.)

This style of development, however, is too complicated.  Avoiding certain pitfalls would greatly simplify it:

1. The Coq standard vector library is too hard to use.  The issue here is exacerbated because of the nested inductives.  It would probably be better to use plain lists and have a separate well-formedness predicate on terms.
2. Defining a relation such as `rela` in proof mode makes it harder to read.  Consider, for instance, the following simpler alternative:

   ```
   Fixpoint rela x y :=
     match y with
     | FVC _ => False
     | FSC f v =>
       Vector.In x v \/
       Vector.fold_right (fun z P => rela x z \/ P) v False
     end.
   ```
3. Folding left has a poor reduction behavior, because it forces us to generalize over the accumulator argument to get the induction to go through.  This is why in my proof I had to switch to a `fold_right`.

Comment: This is an implementation of the 1st advice: https://pastebin.com/kwnbx0Gz . That was not trivial. I also didn't succeed in the extraction of the list of terms(i.e. arguments) from the term. (corresponding function "prototype" is equipped with sketch of proof for redundant cases)

Comment: @ged Instead of propagating the proof from the term, it is easier if you write a function `preterm -> option term` that tries to cast a preterm into a term, and partially map that function over the list of arguments. This approach is described in this gist: https://gist.github.com/arthuraa/2e5e2e8e1209784b3b1f3820d9240982. The code uses the Mathematical Components library, which has good support for this idiom.